# Measure the migration time

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I am using KVM through virt-manager to test the performance in terms of migration speed on different types of network. However, I can't find any documents detailing on measuring the migration time. With libvirt, you basically just execute the migration request and then poll later to check when the migration is finished.

I'm wondering if there is anyway to measure such migration time easily?

Answer (score 1):

Do it from the command line and use the standard unix `time` command:

`time virsh migrate foo destination-uri options...`

for specifics about the command run `virsh migrate help` from a shell.

Edit:  Forgot to add - use the `--verbose` option to have it show progress rather sending the migration process to the background.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how to keep this process foreground until the migration completes

Comment: The verbose option is not available in my virsh. :-/

Comment: launch virsh without any commands and issue the command "help migrate" to see the various options available.  I haven't heard of a version without this.

Comment: Yes I was on Debian. Just switched to Fedora and the option is available

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked personally, but what about libvirt logs (and NTP synced clocks)?

Comment: The log is useful, but the granularity is insufficient